# In Silverlight 4 toolkit sample of AutoCompleteBox, how to toggle drop down in xaml?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Sample taken straight from the Silverlight 4 Toolkit - Samples source code.

We have a style for the AutoCompleteBox to make it like a combobox :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="input:AutoCompleteBox">
              <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                ...
                Click="DropDownToggle_Click">
```

Now, in their sample, they have a click event handler in code behind (listed below), however I was trying to define this method in the xaml ( *i.e. I don't want a code behind file* )

```
private void DropDownToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
            AutoCompleteBox acb = null;
            while (fe != null && acb == null)
            {
                fe = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(fe) as FrameworkElement;
                acb = fe as AutoCompleteBox;
            }
            if (acb != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acb.SearchText))
                {
                    acb.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                acb.IsDropDownOpen = !acb.IsDropDownOpen;
            }
        }
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this in Xaml and not in code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced the whole line (starting with Click=...), with the following;

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I have eliminated the need now for the event handler method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use states for this behaviour. In this case you would define two states: PopupOpen and PopupClosed. The PopupOpen State sets the IsDropDownOpen Property to True and the PopupClosed to false. 
Then you add an DataStateBehaviour and bind it to the IsChecked Property of the toggle button. IsChecked = true = Open, IsChecked = false = Closed

I never tried this, but this should work.

Are you using Blend?

Here you can find some information about the DataStateBehaviour:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723952(v=expression.40).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.datastatebehavior_members(v=expression.40).aspx
http://silverlightforbusiness.net/2010/04/26/using-the-datastatebehavior-for-loading-animations-in-mvvm/

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

EDIT: Try binding the IsOpen Property directly to the IsChecked State of the toggle Button. This should work, too.

Comment: I haven't had success with this yet, I'll try to get it going, but I do have a working solution (see my answer).